# Can Firebase generate 2 identical ID's non case sensitive?

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I just want to know if firebase can auto generate 2 identical document ID's non case sensitive. I know that this is almost impossible, but is there any probability that firebase could auto generate 2 ID's like "aBcDeF" and "abcdEf" ? (I know that firebase Id's are much longer, these are 2 examples).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no its not possible for firebase to generate same document id non case sensitive. The ids are much longer so its impossible to generate that

Comment: It's actually not impossible.  It's just astronomically unlikely, given the size of the IDs, and assuming good entropy with the random number generator on the host machine.  A document ID is effectively just a hash of a large random number.  Two clients could, in theory, generate that same random number.